# set the position for pop up

Tags: jquery

Im new to jquery.
I'm loading the pop up in my asp.net application.
I want set the postion for pop up.
Now its opening at center postion.
please let me know how can I show the pop up on top.
Can I mention the pixels for top postion?
Please let me know how to do it.

here is my code

`var popup = 0;
        $("#modalRightCenterContent").dialog({
            minHeight: 48,
            minWidth: 470,
            resizable: false,
            modal: true,
            autoOpen: false,
            title: "Add Widgets"
        })`

Answer (score 1):

You can set the position as well:

```
$( ".selector" ).dialog({ position: 'top' });
```

Refer to this:

http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#option-position

Answer (score 0):

try add the following code

```
 $('#modalRightCenterContent').css({ top: '1%', left: '50%', margin: '-' + (($('#modalRightCenterContent').height() ) - ($(window).scrollTop())) + 'px 0 0 -' + (($('#modalRightCenterContent').width() / 2)) + 'px' });
```

add this line and you will get top center your dialog